# Plotting two images in Matplotlib on the same axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two images on the same axes. Here is the code I'm experimenting with (I'm new to MatplotLib - so apologies in advance)...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms

img = plt.imread('image1.gif')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

rotation_in_degrees = 60

tr = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(rotation_in_degrees)

ax.imshow(img)

ax.imshow(img, transform=tr)

plt.show()
```

There are two issues. Firstly, only the first image appears in the display; the second is only partially shown. Is there a way to show the two images in the same plot? That is, the axes are automatically scaled.

Secondly, as you can see, I'm trying to rotate the image but I'm sure that I'm not doing correctly in the sense I don't know if I'm rotating it around the origin of the plot etc. Any advice or links for other posts would be great!

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your firs problem - you need to display each image in separate subplot, now - you are plotting in the same subplot. See example of plotting in separate plots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms

img = plt.imread('image.gif')
fig = plt.figure()
rotation_in_degrees = 60
tr = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(rotation_in_degrees)

ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.imshow(img)
ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

For the second issue with rotation - I would use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html):

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('image.gif')
fig = plt.figure()
rotation_in_degrees = 60

ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.imshow(img)

img2 = img.rotate(rotation_in_degrees)
ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.imshow(img2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but I don't think I explained myself well enough. I don't want two plots, rather I want the two images to appear on one "plot" e.g. an x/y grid with the one image and the other rotated image on the same set of axes.